# Validacion de formulario con HTML5 y JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html5, textarea

Tengo un problema con un formulario. 
Particularmente con el elemento **text-area**. 
La validación es simple. 
Si el elemento esta vacio, se ejecuta un borde rojo.
Si el elemento contiene caracteres (hasta 500), se ejecuta un borde verde y el formulario se envia sin problemas. 
Ahora bien, lo estuve testeando en el servidor local y tiene un **bug**. 
Mientras no hay nada en el elemento tiene un borde rojo, apenas escribo algo el borde cambia a verde. Eso funciona perfecto, PERO... Si borro lo que escribi y el elemento vuelve a quedar vacío, me lo sigue enmarcando en verde y el formulario se envía con el elemento vacío. 
Alguna idea? 
Adjunto codigo JS.

```
function validarForm() {
  nombre.addEventListener("input", validarNombre);
  email.addEventListener("input", validarEmail);
  mensaje.addEventListener("input", validarMensaje);
  validarNombre();
  validarEmail();
  validarMensaje();
}

function validarMensaje() {
  if (nombre.value == "") {
    mensaje.setCustomValidity("Por favor detalle como podríamos ayudarlo");
    mensaje.style.borderColor = "#E22E11";
  } else if (mensaje.value != "") {
    mensaje.setCustomValidity("");
    mensaje.style.borderColor = "#3D8B44";
  }
}
window.addEventListener("load", validarForm);
```

Adjunto codigo HTML del elemento

```
<label class="mensaje-label" for="mensaje">Mensaje</label>
          <textarea
            class="mensaje-textarea"
            id="mensaje"
            placeholder="Escriba su mensaje. Máximo 500 caracteres."
            maxlength="500"
          ></textarea>
```

Comment: Agrega el atributo `required` en el `textarea`, así el formulario no será enviado si el campo está vacío. `<textarea class="mensaje-textarea" id="mensaje" placeholder="Escriba su mensaje. Máximo 500 caracteres." maxlength="500" required></textarea>`

Comment: Podrias poner en algun lado una funcion que escuche cuando se presionen teclas sobre el text-area, ``$("#mensaje").on("keyup", function(){ }``, y dentro de la funcion evaluar, si el tamaño del contenido del text area es menor a 1, cambiar el borde a rojo, de lo contrario mantenerlo azul  ``if($("#mensaje").val().length) < 1){}``

Comment: @Mani tiene razón en la mayoria de su observación sin embargo si agregan caracteres en blanco el tamaño va a ser mayor o igual a 1. Lo correcto estaria en darle un **trim** al value del text-area para que te elimine los espacios en blanco.

Comment: Probe con "required" y funciona.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primera cosa que deberías hacer es colocarle un required al textarea:

```
 <textarea
          class="mensaje-textarea"
          id="mensaje"
          placeholder="Escriba su mensaje. Máximo 500 caracteres."
          maxlength="500"
          required>
 </textarea>
```

De esta manera si el textarea no tiene contenido no va a enviarse el formulario, ademas ten en cuenta que si le colocas el atributo required, al hacer blur al textarea sin que este tenga contenido, se te colocara automáticamente un borde rojo... esto en navegadores como chrome, creo que en otros también... si no deseas usar este borde rojo del navegador si no hay contenido en el textarea, quita el required, pero entonces deberás prevenir que se envié la información de manera manual.

Ahora bien lo que dice DavElsanto es correcto, deberías colocarle un trim a las validaciones:

```
function validarMensaje() {
  if (nombre.value.trim() == "") {
    mensaje.setCustomValidity("Por favor detalle como podríamos ayudarlo");
    mensaje.style.borderColor = "#E22E11";
  } else if (mensaje.value.trim() != "") {
    mensaje.setCustomValidity("");
    mensaje.style.borderColor = "#3D8B44";
  }
}
```

Ahora, tu bug de que cuando borras todo se te queda de todas maneras el textarea con el borde verde, se debe a que no tienes una tercera condición donde compruebes que efectivamente la cantidad de caracteres es cero o "", es decir, tu compruebas que mensaje no sea igual a "", pero no compruebas también lo contrario:

```
function validarMensaje() {
  if (nombre.value.trim() == "") {
    mensaje.setCustomValidity("Por favor detalle como podríamos ayudarlo");
    mensaje.style.borderColor = "#E22E11";
  } else if (mensaje.value.trim() != "") {
    mensaje.setCustomValidity("");
    mensaje.style.borderColor = "#3D8B44";
  }else if(mensaje.value.trim() === ""){
    /*No se que hace la función setCustomValidity, pero supongo que te
     *permite mostrar un mensaje en pantalla*/
    mensaje.setCustomValidity("Es obligatorio este contenido!");
    mensaje.style.borderColor = "#E22E11";
  }
}
```

Que de hecho teniendo en cuenta esto, también tendrías que tener el mismo problema con el campo nombre, así que te recomiendo que crees otro condicional para el caso del campo nombre, de lo contrario tendrás el mismo error pero con el campo nombre, entonces al final quedaría así:

```
function validarMensaje() {
  if (nombre.value.trim() == "") {
    mensaje.setCustomValidity("Por favor detalle como podríamos ayudarlo");
    mensaje.style.borderColor = "#E22E11";
  }if(nombre.value.trim() != ""){
    mensaje.setCustomValidity("");
    mensaje.style.borderColor = "#3D8B44";
  } if (mensaje.value.trim() != "") {
    mensaje.setCustomValidity("");
    mensaje.style.borderColor = "#3D8B44";
  }if(mensaje.value.trim() === ""){
    /*No se que hace la función setCustomValidity, pero supongo que te
     *permite mostrar un mensaje en pantalla*/
    mensaje.setCustomValidity("Es obligatorio este contenido!");
    mensaje.style.borderColor = "#E22E11";
  }
}
```

Como vez, también habrás notado que hice de cada uno de los else if y else que hubiesen, los convertí en if, esto debido a que todos deberian ejecutarse, si pones else if seguido de un if, o un else seguido de un else if, solo se ejecutara el primero que se cumpla y no el resto... si los hubiese dejado como else ifs, lo que hubiese pasado seguramente es que te creaba el borde verde en un campo y no en el otro o viceversa, pero no en ambos, es decir, funcionaria una cosa bien pero no la otra.

Comment: Ahhh otra cosa que me di cuenta por si depronto el código falla, es que en las partes donde compruebas que nombre tenga contenido o en el otro donde compurebas que no tenga contenido, dentro, le asignaste a la variable mensaje unas cosas y estilos... ¿Si estas comprobando que nombre tenga o no tenga contenido no deberias es cambiar la variable nombre y no la variable mensaje?, ten en cuenta esto, creo que ahí como que tienes otro error, deberías corregirlo en tu código original, a no ser de que me equivoque y realmente lo hicieras a proposito...

Comment: Perfecto! Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Hay algo mucho mas simple que todo eso, lo mas sencillo de hacer para verificar campos vacíos con js es por ejemplo donde tu pones  `if (nombre.value == "")` puedes cambiarlo por `if (nombre.value.length==0)`Solo tendrías que cambiar eso en todos los campos, y así te aseguras de que no estén vacíos, es mucho mas sencillo que lo que has hecho, espero que te sirva paro lo que quieres.

Answer (score 1):

Lo más sencillo es que  para verificar campos vacíos con js es por ejemplo donde tu pones `if (nombre.value == "")` puedes cambiarlo por `if (nombre.value.length==0)`, así verificas que el campo no se quede vacío.